# If agglomeration is false, is deontic trivialism possibly true?

Tags: logic, ethics, dilemma

Agglomeration, in deontic logic, is the rule that says: OB*A*, OB*B*, therefore OB(*A*&*B*). There is a quick argument from agglomeration to the nonexistence of at least one kind of irresolvable moral dilemma: such a dilemma appears in the form of OB*A*, OB~*A*, therefore OB(*A*&~*A*), i.e. you would be obligated to bring about a contradiction. Supposing that ought-implies-can, this would mean that it was possible for a contradiction to be true. But assuming the law of noncontradiction, this must not be the case; ergo...

On the other hand, if you deny agglomeration, then the above kind of irresolvable moral dilemma doesn't manifest.

Alethic trivialism is when every proposition is true. That contradictions would lead to alethic trivialism (AKA the doctrine of logical explosions) is taken for evidence (so to speak) that the law of noncontradiction is true, instead. Deontic trivialism would be when everything is obligated.

I haven't been able to design the argument to give us the stronger conclusion, "If agglomeration is false, then deontic trivialism is *actually* true." But it seems to me that negating agglomeration leads to, "Deontic trivialism *could* be(come) true." For suppose you had a list of all actions possible at a given time: *a*<sub>1</sub>, *a*<sub>2</sub>, etc. Usually, because it is impossible to perform every *a*<sub>*n*</sub> at the same time, we would say that not every one of the *a*<sub>*n*</sub> could be obligatory. However, if such impossibility is not an issue (due to the lack of agglomeration), then why *couldn't* all the *a*<sub>*n*</sub> be simultaneously obligatory?

I imagine we could just throw in, as a basic premise, "Even though some contradictory sets of actions can be obligatory, it is never true that every such set can be obligatory." How *ad hoc* of a solution would this be, though? (You might try out, "*A* is obligatory iff it is deducible in the appropriate system; in some such system, it is possible to infer that ~*A* is also obligatory; but it is never possible to infer that every *A* whatsoever is obligatory..." But again, how should this be so?)

Comment: Even for *non*-contradictory sets of actions only some are ever obligatory, and it is not *ad hoc* at all. Ethics is supposed to serve as a guide to action, throwing in too many obligations defeats the purpose. Aside from purely logical rules, your deontic system must have some substantive postulates, and *they* must be chosen to preclude trivialism (and much more besides) even if logic by itself does not block it. Otherwise, it is useless. By the way, trivial propositional systems are ruled out the same way, they lack discriminative power to be of any use.

Comment: There are ethical philosophers who have disputed the action-guidance thesis. I am, in the end, addressing them, since it is they who (in philosophy) think that irresolvable moral dilemmas exist (are examples of genuine moral states of affairs that are not sufficiently action-guiding). I suppose the next level of the argument would be: if ethics is *not* action-guiding, then deontic trivialism could be true.

Comment: Believing in irresolvable moral dilemmas does not thereby dispute the action-guidance thesis, often it simply acknowledges that ethics must sometimes fail to do its job, perhaps for deep seated reasons. This world isn't perfect. And even non-actional morality seeks to *distinguish*, good from bad, so you are not addressing them either. It is also unclear what "could be true" even means. Is it logically possible to construct some such "deontic system"? Sure. Is it of interest as ethics? Probably not.

Comment: You could have a negative deontic trivialism, where every action is forbidden. You can still distinguish between the *concepts* of the obligatory and the forbidden. Suppose there were a world where everything was colored red, but it was possible for things to change color, or for things to be colored differently. Would this mean that we could not at all distinguish between red and not-red, in that world? Of course not.

Comment: Also, from [the SEP article on moral dilemmas](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-dilemmas/): "Ethicists who are concerned that their theories not allow for moral dilemmas have more than consistency in mind. What is troubling is that theories that allow for dilemmas fail to be uniquely action-guiding. A theory can fail to be uniquely action-guiding in either of two ways: by recommending incompatible actions in a situation or by not recommending any action at all. Theories that generate genuine moral dilemmas fail to be uniquely action-guiding in the former way. [cont]

Comment: Theories that have no way, even in principle, of determining what an agent should do in a particular situation have what Thomas E. Hill, Jr. calls “gaps” (Hill 1996, 179–183); they fail to be action-guiding in the latter way. Since one of the main points of moral theories is to provide agents with guidance, that suggests that it is desirable for theories to eliminate dilemmas and gaps, at least if doing so is possible."

Comment: I don't see why the negation of agglomeration would lead to trivialism. If there are non-agglomerative obligations that conflict, then we might say that they are just prima facie obligations and one dominates the others. This does not make everything obligatory, though perhaps some artificial scenario could be designed under which all the available options have some measure of obligation.